# Formatting finalPrice

Tags: price

I've been looking through guides and other questions, but I simply can't get the finalPrice formatted as I want.
I would like to display the price with the chosen currency first and then the price with two decimals, e.g. as;

```
$4.00
```

Im retreiving the price with the following line;

```
echo $product->getFinalPrice();
```

This simply displays on the front-end as;

```
4
```

I've also tried using the following line;

```
echo $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($finalPrice, true, false);
```

This gives me the right formatting, but doesn't retreive the actual price of the product. It display as;

```
€0.00
```

The one gets the actual price and the other formats it the way I want, so I guess I have to combine these in some way?

Comment: have you tried `echo $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getFinalPrice(), true, false);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line is the correct answer:

```
echo $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($finalPrice, true, false);
```

However, you're getting a value of `€0.00` because the `$finalPrice` variable isn't set to anything.  This should resolve that issue:

```
$finalPrice = $product->getFinalPrice();
echo $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($finalPrice, true, false);
```

Or, you can combine both into a single line, like @Marius suggested:

```
echo $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getFinalPrice(), true, false);
```

Comment: You can also use Mage::helper('core')->formatCurrency($_finalPrice, false);